# static pages in rails app missing template

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes

I have to add a static page to my rails app.

Here's the logic I am following.

I made a directory called `pages` and put a file called `signup.html.erb` there.

The path in my another html file is `pages/signup`

In my `routes.rb`, I have `get 'pages/signup'`

I made a `pages controller` and there I have something like below

```
class PagesController < ApplicationController

  def signup
  end


end
```

I get below error.

> Missing template pages/signup, application/signup with

What's wrong here?

Comment: run the rake routes command from the root of the application, The actual problem you then easily get and solved by user self.

Comment: its a spree app so `rake routes` gives all those results related to spree.

Comment: Hey, then there is a gem for managing the static pages in spree.https://github.com/spree-contrib/spree_static_content ,that will solved your problem.

Comment: The full path of the html file should be `app/views/pages/signup.html.erb`. Can you confirm that you created the view file in that path?

Comment: since Its a spree app so I put the file in `app/views/spree/pages/signup.html.erb`

Comment: Since you didn't add your controller into the spree namespace I think that is wrong. Please test the other location.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just write in routs.rb

```
get '/pages/signup', to: 'pages#signup'
```

and in pages_controller.rb write

```
def signup
   @page = Page.new
end
def create
# write create function
end
```

Answer (score 0):

In my routes.rb, try

```
get 'pages/signup'
match "signup", :to => "pages#signup"
```

on rails 4

```
get 'pages/signup'
match "signup", :to => "pages#signup", via: :all
```

Answer (score 0):

Because your controller isn't in the spree namespace change the full path of the html file from

```
app/views/spree/pages/signup.html.erb
```

to

```
app/views/pages/signup.html.erb
```